# $P[X<Y]$ expression for $X$ with a infinite range and $Y$ with finite range

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables. The range of $X$ is infinite, say $[a,\infty)$ while the support of the $Y$ is finite, say $[b,c]$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all positive real numbers such that $a\leq b<c<\infty$. I would like to find $\mathbb{P}[X<Y]$. Here is my trial:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X<Y)&=\mathbb{P}(X<Y|X\in[a,b])\mathbb{P}(X \in [a,b]) +\mathbb{P}(X<Y|X\in[b,c])\mathbb{P}(X \in [b,c]) +\mathbb{P}(X<Y|X\in[c,\infty])\mathbb{P}(X \in [c,\infty])\\
&=\mathbb{P}(X∈[a,b))+\mathbb{P}(X<Y|X∈[b,c])P(X∈[b,c])\\
&= \int_{a}^{b}\, f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{b}^{c}F_X(y)\, f_Y(y) \,\mathrm{d}y 
\end{align*}

Is this correct?

Comment: A probability that exceeds $1$?!... No of course it is not correct. BTW  $P(X<Y)$ only makes sense if $(X,Y)$ have joint distribution, and can only be calculated if this distribution is determined. Further we have $P(A)=P(A\mid B)P(B)+P(A\mid C)P(C)+P(A\mid E)P(E)$ if $B,C,E$ are disjoint and cover the whole space. Not  $P(A)=P(A\mid B)+P(A\mid C)+P(A\mid E)$ as you seem to think.

Comment: @drhb Yeah it seems that I have misused the law of total probability. Thank you I have edited that. But with regard to your first comment, why is it the case?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables both defined on probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ then $\{X<Y\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)<Y(\omega)\}\in\mathcal A$ and $P(X<Y)\in[0,1]$ can be computed. But for that it is not enough to know the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ separately. Needed is the *joint distribution*. In lots of cases $X,Y$ are *independent* but that info lacks in your question. Further in principle $X$ and $Y$ can be random variables that are defined on distinct probability spaces. In that case there is no set $\{X<Y\}$.

Comment: I suspect that in your question $X$ and $Y$ are independent. If so then you should add that information to your question. It indicates that $X,Y$ are defined on the same probability space and that $F_{X}(x)F_{Y}(y)$ is their joint CDF.

Comment: @drhab yes I am considering that $X$ and $Y$ are independent yet I forgot to mention it. In such case, would my edited solution be true then?

Comment: When you conditioned by $X \in [a,b)$ and $X\in (c,\infty)$ you obtain that :
$$P(X<Y|X\in [a,b)) = 1;$$
$$P(X<Y|X\in [c,\infty)) = 0.$$
It follows that
$$ P(X<Y)=P(X\in[a,b)) + P(X<Y|X\in [b,c])P(X\in[b,c]) = 1.$$

Comment: @Cuoredicervo do you mean that $P(X<Y)$ is always equal to $1$? I don't believe so.

Comment: @Lod I'm sorry, I have copied the formula from the previous step and I don't delete the value 1. My comment is an starting point for the conclusion.
The correct answer :
$$P(X<Y)=P(X∈[a,b))+P(X<Y|X∈[b,c])P(X∈[b,c])$$

Comment: @Cuoredicervo Oh yeah It seems that mt answer was for $\mathbb{P}(X>Y)$ instead of $\mathbb{P}(X<Y)$. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first place it looks as if you accidently went for $\mathbb P(X>Y)$ instead of $\mathbb P(X<Y)$.

A good start is:

$$\begin{aligned}\mathbb{P}\left(X<Y\right) & =\mathbb{P}\left(X<Y\mid X<b\right)\mathbb{P}\left(a\leq X<b\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(X<Y\mid b\leq X\leq c\right)\mathbb{P}\left(b\leq X\leq c\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(X<Y\mid X>c\right)\mathbb{P}\left(X>c\right)\\
 & =\mathbb{P}\left(a\leq X<b\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(X<Y\mid b\leq X\leq c\right)\mathbb{P}\left(b\leq X\leq c\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Secondly we have:$$\mathbb{P}\left(X<Y\mid b\leq X\leq c\right)\mathbb{P}\left(b\leq X\leq c\right)=\mathbb P(X<Y\wedge b\leq X\leq c)=\mathbb E\mathbf1_{X<Y}\mathbf 1_{b\leq X\leq c}$$$$=\int^c_b\mathbb P(x<Y)f_X(x)dx$$In your answer you seem to think however that the LHS of this equality should be $\mathbb{P}\left(X<Y\mid b\leq X\leq c\right)$ which is wrong.

So our final result is:$$\mathbb P(X<Y)=\mathbb P(a\leq X<b)+\int^c_b\mathbb P(x<Y)f_X(x)dx=F_X(b)+\int_b^c(1-F_Y(x))f_X(x)dx$$

Comment: I believe there's a typo. The equations before and after "and **not**"  are the *same*. Also, isn't $\mathbb P(a\leq X<b) = F_X(b) - F_X(a)$? And thank you!

Comment: But $F_X(a)=0$ right? No, they are not the same. E.g. we do not have $P(X\in A\mid X\in A)=\int_A1f_X(x)=P(A)$ but we have $P(X\in A\mid X\in A)=1$.

Comment: What I mean to say is that the factor $\int^b_cf_X(x)dx$ in your answer is wrong and should not be there.

Comment: Yeah it is indeed zero. What I mean by the same is that you wrote that $\mathbb{P}\left(X<Y\mid b\leq X\leq c\right)$ is equal to $\int^c_b\mathbb P(x<Y)f_X(x)dx$ twice, right? I am not sure what is the mistake you were trying to highlight.

Comment: First equality is $\mathbb P(X<Y\mid b\leq X\leq c)P(b\leq X\leq c)=\cdots$ which is correct. Second equality is $\mathbb P(X<Y\mid b\leq X\leq c)=\cdots$ which is wrong.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}\left(X<Y\mid b\leq X\leq c\right)\mathbb{P}\left(b\leq X\leq c\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(X<Y\wedge b\leq X\leq c\right)=\int_{b}^{c}\mathbb{P}\left(x<Y\right)f_{X}\left(x\right)dx\neq\mathbb{P}\left(X<Y\mid b\leq X\leq c\right)$

Comment: Oh yeah I see! Thank you that's pretty clear now.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your law ot total probability is wrong - you should have:

$$\mathbb{P}(X<Y)=\mathbb{P}(X<Y|X\in[a,b])\mathbb{P}(X \in [a,b])+\mathbb{P}(X<Y|X\in[b,c])\mathbb{P}(X \in [b,c])+\mathbb{P}(X<Y|X\in[c,\infty])\mathbb{P}(X \in [c,\infty])$$

Comment: Thank you I have considered this and altered my solution.